# Using RegEx and Quill JS to make a set of banned words bold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, rich-text-editor, quill

I'm trying to create a simple page where when you submit text to the server it checks against a list of banned words, and any found are made bold. Since textarea can't have formatting I'd decided to use Quill JS for the rich text area. Because of the index property on Quills insertText function it finds the banned words then inserts them in the wrong place. Is there a way to have the words replaced where they should be?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Syntax Highlighting</title>
<!-- Main Quill library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style> #editor-container { height: 130px; } </style>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="form-container" class="container">
        <form name="badwords" method="post" action="" >
            <div class="row form-group">
              <label for="about">Appraisal Info</label>
              <input name="about" type="hidden">

              <div id="editor-container">

              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="formSub" type="submit">Submit!</button>
          </div>    
        </form>
    </div>
 </body>

 <script src="U:\Code Examples\Highlighting\parch.js"></script>
 <link href="U:\Code Examples\Highlighting\style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementById('formSub'); 

function replaceWords(event) {
    //Prevent form submission to server 
    event.preventDefault();
    var commentContent = quill.getText();
    var badWords = ["green", "red", "blue"];
    console.log(commentContent)
    commentContent =censore(commentContent, badWords);
}   

function censore(string, filters) {
    console.log('in')
    // "i" is to ignore case and "g" for global "|" for OR match
    var regex = new RegExp(filters.join("|"), "gi");
    return string.replace(regex, function (match) {
        //replace 
        var clean = match;
        console.log(clean);
        return quill.insertText(0, clean, 'bold', true);
    });
}
div.addEventListener('click',replaceWords); 
</script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution would be to look differently for your words using Quill API and then **apply bold format** rather than insert with `insertText`

But another quick solution would be also to use your regex to wrap these words with `<strong>` markup and then use Quill clipboard [pasteHTML method](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#dangerouslypastehtml) to replace all the content with yours with the bold markup

Comment: The issue there is the XSS vulnerabilities. I've tried using the Quill API to make those words bold but couldn't get it to. Any ideas?

Comment: I do not understand your XSS vulnerability problem. Even if you paste your html code with bold word, you just could perfectly send the `quill.getText()` to your API (and check there again if forbidden words are present). Manipulating html in your quill editor and what you send to your backend are two different things